# Chern classes of a rank two vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-geometry, characteristic-classes, coherent-sheaves

Let $\mathcal{I}_p$ be the ideal sheaf of a point $p\in\mathbb{P}^2$, and let $\mathcal{E}$ be the rank two locally free sheaf over $\mathbb{P}^2$ determined by the following exact sequence:
$$0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}\rightarrow \mathcal{E}\rightarrow \mathcal{I}_{p}\rightarrow 0.$$
How could one compute the Chern classes of $\mathcal{E}$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Of course $c(\mathcal E) = c(I_p)$. Computing the Chern class of $I_p$ can be done with the sequence $$ 0 \to I_p \to O_{\Bbb P^2} \to O_p \to 0 $$ which is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749776/chern-class-of-ideal-sheaf). You obtain $c_1(I_p) = 0$ and $c_2(I_p) = 1$.